# Create "history" to SearchView on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I want to have history on my SearchView, I've been googling around, and the only sensible(?) tutorial I found was [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html), but that's just for like Gingerbread, not API>14.

Then I found this code:

```
String[] columnNames = {"_id","text"};
        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
        String[] array = {"Snääälla", "bla bla bla", "Jävla piss"}; //if strings are in resources
        String[] temp = new String[2];
        int id = 0;
        for(String item : array){
            temp[0] = Integer.toString(id++);
            temp[1] = item;
            cursor.addRow(temp);
        }
        String[] from = {"text"};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
        CursorAdapter ad = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to);
        mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(ad);
```

And that code only works half, since it doesn't show results from what you've already written, it shows all the items.

I just want it to look like this:

[image: Google Play Store screnshot]

This is my current code for adding the SearchView:

res/menu/menu.xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/fragment_searchmenuitem"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
      android:title="@string/menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    if(!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_search, menu);

        mMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.fragment_searchmenuitem);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) mMenuItem.getActionView();
        mMenuItem.expandActionView();
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                mMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                searchSupport.SearchForLyrics(s);
                actionBar.setSubtitle("Searcing for: " + s);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Could someone please just give me something to start with, to be honest I have no idea where to start. So any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: have u ever thought of saving them in your data bas then using the auto complete textview retrieve it from the data base using cursor adapter

Comment: @TerrilThomas Yes, yes I do. But I was hoping that Google would have some official APIs or something to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page talks about how you can implement history for SearchView.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html

First, you have to create a content provider:

```
public class MySuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.MySuggestionProvider";
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

    public MySuggestionProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }
}
```

Then declare the content provider in your application manifest like this:

```
<application>
    <provider android:name=".MySuggestionProvider"
              android:authorities="com.example.MySuggestionProvider" />
    ...
</application>
```

Then add the content provider to your searchable configurations like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.MySuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" >
</searchable>
```

You can call saveRecentQuery() to save queries at any time. Here's how you can do it in the onCreate method for your activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent  = getIntent();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
                MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
        suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);
    }
}
```

To clear search history you simply need to call **SearchRecentSuggestions**'s method **clearHistory()** like this:

```
SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
        HelloSuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, HelloSuggestionProvider.MODE);
suggestions.clearHistory();
```

Comment: This solution is incomplete and needs to be mixed with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar. If found out it's best to implement a custom suggestion adapter if the app is themed in any ways.

Comment: Hello, if I want to get all recent search suggestions from the suggestion database and show it when the user didn't write anything search view.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Fragment for SeaarchView on ActionBar so I have my own listener like "setOnSuggestionListener", "setOnQueryTextListener". When I write searchview.setSearchableInfo(), my adapter stops working. So I looked at "setSearchableInfo" function and I extract some code for getting history search data myself from core code.

```
class MySearchableInfoClass internal constructor(
private val mContext: Context,
private val mSearchable: SearchableInfo
 ) {

private val QUERY_LIMIT = 5


private fun getSearchManagerSuggestions(
    searchable: SearchableInfo?,
    query: String,
    limit: Int
): Cursor? {
    if (searchable == null) {
        return null
    }

    val authority = searchable.suggestAuthority ?: return null

    val uriBuilder = Uri.Builder()
        .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)
        .authority(authority)
        .query("")  // TODO: Remove, workaround for a bug in Uri.writeToParcel()
        .fragment("")  // TODO: Remove, workaround for a bug in Uri.writeToParcel()

    // if content path provided, insert it now
    val contentPath = searchable.suggestPath
    if (contentPath != null) {
        uriBuilder.appendEncodedPath(contentPath)
    }

    // append standard suggestion query path
    uriBuilder.appendPath(SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY)

    // get the query selection, may be null
    val selection = searchable.suggestSelection
    // inject query, either as selection args or inline
    var selArgs: Array<String>? = null
    if (selection != null) {    // use selection if provided
        selArgs = arrayOf(query)
    } else {                    // no selection, use REST pattern
        uriBuilder.appendPath(query)
    }

    if (limit > 0) {
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("limit", limit.toString())
    }

    val uri = uriBuilder.build()

    // finally, make the query
    return mContext.contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, selArgs, null)
}

fun getSearchHistoryCursor(constraint: CharSequence?): Cursor? {
    val query = constraint?.toString() ?: ""
    var cursor: Cursor? = null

    try {
        cursor = getSearchManagerSuggestions(mSearchable, query, QUERY_LIMIT)
        // trigger fill window so the spinner stays up until the results are copied over and
        // closer to being ready
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.count
            return cursor
        }
    } catch (e: RuntimeException) {

    }

    // If cursor is null or an exception was thrown, stop the spinner and return null.
    // changeCursor doesn't get called if cursor is null
    return null
}
}
```

getSearchHistoryCursor returns a cursor so you can getString or anythingelse and eventually search history.

Example:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("suggest_text_1")))
```