# Implement SearchView history without "searchable" declaration

Tags: android, searchview

I want to add search history to my SearchView. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166537/create-history-to-searchview-on-actionbar) question. It is rather useful but it looks like I can't handle it this way. First of all I use only fragments in my app while it looks like the solution above requires to create new activity for making search (well maybe I can reuse the same activity using some `Intent` flags). Also I can't provide search hint bia string resources.

I have fragment with `SearchView` in actionbar. When user enters search query I just perform web request and display results in the same fragment. I only need to add search history functionality to it. Can this be done completly programmatically?

Comment: Just call setSuggestionsAdapter with a SimpleCursorAdapter that has set custom FilterQueryProvider

Comment: In your FilterQueryProvider you can comcombine two cursors (historical search results and current search results)  by using a MergeCursor