# How to show search view recent search history

Tags: android, android-sqlite, searchview, android-search, android-sharedpreferences

I tried to using following ways but unable to show recent search history

[Create "history" to SearchView on ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166537/create-history-to-searchview-on-actionbar)

[Implementing SearchView in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar)

kindly help how to create and show recent search in serachview searchable xml

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

1. create an xml file called `searchable.xml` (in res/xml)

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"    
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="your packagename.MySuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" >
    </searchable>
   ```
2. create a content provider class that extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider :

   ```
    public class MySuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {

    public final static String AUTHORITY = "your package name.MySuggestionProvider";
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

    public MySuggestionProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }
   }
   ```
3. in your activity's class `onCreate` method

   ```
    handleSearch(getIntent());
   ```
4. override this method:

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       setIntent(intent);

       handleSearch(intent);
    }

    public void handleSearch( Intent intent)
    {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        mtToolbar.setTitle(query);

            SearchRecentSuggestions searchRecentSuggestions=new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
                    MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY,MySuggestionProvider.MODE);

            searchRecentSuggestions.saveRecentQuery(query,null);
        }
    }
   ```
5. in the menu

   ```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);

        SearchManager searchManager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView searchView;

        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
        }
        else
        {
            searchView=(SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        }

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

These are step i am using

```
 Searchable xml file 

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="example.com.cle.MySuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
    >
</searchable>




Provider 


        <provider android:name=".MySuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="example.com.cle.MySuggestionProvider" />


Activity in manifiest

 <activity
            android:name=".BaseActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>


            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />


Activity class

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
                    MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
            suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);


        }
    }


Content provider class 

public final static String AUTHORITY ="example.com.cle.MySuggestionProvider";
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

    public MySuggestionProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }
```